# How to create a yeoman generator without yo prefix?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am creating a command line generator for improve productive with nodejs server development, The most widely used generator is `yeoman`, so I choice it for creating command line tool, But there is problem that how to use generator without `yo` prefix?

```
yo tuols
```

But I wanna use `tuols` command without `yo` prefix

```
tuols
```

How to do that?

Comment: have you made it worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the Yeoman documentation http://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html